# Convert Console output into a PDF file

Tags: java, eclipse, pdf, itext

So I have this code here that calls a private function from a different class and from a different package.

```
public class ClassName {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  
{

    Display display = new Display();
    InformationReceiver info = new InformationReceiver ();
    display.getDetails(info);
}}
```

My question is that. . 
How can I make the console output of this code/everything that the called function(display.getDetails) prints out into a PDF file.

I've already made and imported an itext library into my eclpise compiler.
I'm just having problems with the syntax itself.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Java and Javascript are completely different programming languages. Which one is this?

Comment: Ohhh, sorry. This is just java. Apologies.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the System.out via the following command System.setOut(out);

Now System.out accepts PrintStream.  What you can do is to pass your own implementation of this PRintStream that actually writes everything in PDF format. This is one idea.

Also you can override System.err the same way.